# Error "unknown local index 'post_core' in search request"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I wanna put Thinking Sphinx in my project Ruby On Rails, 
I am using ROR version 3.2.1 and Thinking sphinx 3
i getting error **unknown local index 'post_core' in search request**
browser said that my error in my View

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <li><%= post.content %></li>
<% end %>
```

Anyone can helping me about this?

Answer (score 0):

You might have already solved your problem, but here goes anyway. Maybe it'll help someone else.

The reason for this problem is that you're using Thinking Sphinx 3.0 or newer, but probably defining your indexes the old way, like it was done in Thinking Sphinx 2.* and earlier. The index definitions are no longer in the models themselves but in separate files, which are placed in `app/indices`. There have also been lots of other changes, so it's best to read the new documentation carefully.

The documentation for 3.0 is in the README file: https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/

The "official" documentation still refers to the older version, which works differently: http://pat.github.com/ts/en/